# error while executing search query of elasticsearch

Tags: angularjs

I use *elasticsearch* using *angularjs*. I use search query to search whether document present in *elasticsearch* with particular matching term, then query return response. And i want to access `response.hits.max_score` from response but it generate type error:

> Type Error: Unable to get property 'hits' of undefined or null
>   reference

```
var serch = function() {
    es.search({
        index: 'index1',
        type: 'type1',
        body: {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
        }
    }).then(function(response) {});
    $scope.result = response.hits.max_score;
}
```

Comment: Please add your [mcve](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign respounse.hits.max_score to $scope variable in function available in  .then body. solution show in below code:
    es.search({
                        index: 'dash',
                        type:'node',
                        body: {
                        "query":
                              {
                                  "match": {
                                    "hostname":name.hostname
                                           }
                              },
                             }
                           }).then(function (response) {
                          $scope.result = response.hits.max_score;
                          });